# How to use void methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods, void

I need to display the following information

```
Enter size of array: 3
Enter student name: jane doe
Enter student id number: 14234567
Enter student name: john doe
Enter student id number: 12345678
Enter student name: peter griffin
Enter student id number: 14238251
Array Contents
jane doe 14234567
john doe 12345678
peter griffin
14238251
```

i have to use the following methods

To ask the user for the size they wish the array to be and then create an array of type
Student of the specified size.

```
public static Student[] createArray()
```

To populate the array by asking the user to input a name and ID number for each object
stored within the array

```
public static void populateArray(Student[] array)
```

To displays the contents of the array

```
public static void displayArray(Student[] array)
```

This is what I have so far

```
class Student {

    //private instances
    private String name = "unassigned";
    private long idNumber = 0;

    //Default constructor
    public Student() {
    name = "Not Given";
    idNumber = 0;
    }

    //Constructs a new Student with passed name and age parameters.
    public Student(String studentName, long studentIdNumber) {
    name = studentName;
    idNumber = studentIdNumber;
    }

    //Returns the name of this student.
    public String getName( ) {
        return name;
    }

    // Returns the idNumber of this person.
    public long getIdNumber( ) {
        return idNumber;
    }       

    //Sets the name of this student.
    public void setName(String studentName ) {
        name = studentName;
    }

    //Sets the idNumber of this student.
    public void setIdNumber(long studentIdNumber ) {
        idNumber = studentIdNumber;
    }


} // end class
```

and

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentTest {

    static int array;

    //create method createArray
    public static Student[] createArray() {

        Scanner int_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //user enters size of array         
        System.out.print("Enter Size of Array: ");
        array = int_input.nextInt();

        //create array
        Student[] array = new Student[0];                   
        return array;//return array

    }//end method   

    //create method populateArray
    public static void populateArray(Student[] array) {

        try (Scanner string_input = new Scanner(System.in);
             Scanner long_input = new Scanner(System.in);)
        {               
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                Student arrays = new Student();

                //set name
                System.out.println("Enter Student Name: ");
                arrays.setName(string_input.nextLine());

                //set ID number
                System.out.println("Enter Student ID Number: ");
                arrays.setIdNumber(long_input.nextLong());

                System.out.println();

            }//end for loop
        }//end try loop                             
    }//end method

    //create method display Array
    public static void displayArray(Student[] array){

        System.out.println("Array Contents");
        System.out.println();

    }//end method

    public static void main(String [] args){

        //display createArray method
        System.out.println(createArray());

        //display populateArray method
        System.out.println();

        //display array contents
        System.out.println();

    }//end main method
}//end class
```

my question is how do i get the populateArray method to allow me to enter data into it and then display it? and get the displayArray method to display? I have tried a number of different things but i can't figure it out

Comment: Possible typo here: Student[] array = new Student[0]; I think the 0 should actually be the integer variable "array" about from the input. That being said, you re-use the variable name array for your static int and Student[] array. In general, I'd recommend never using the word "array" as a variable name. Something like "students" or "student" would fit better.

Comment: Create a `ToString` method in your `Student` class that returns a string with the name and ID. Then you can iterate thru the `Student[]` array and just call `toString` on each object. You have a lot of really basic issues with your code, you need to go to your professor/TA/teacher (`createArray` asks for input but then throws it away, duplicate variable names... etc etc). Your `Student` object looks okay actually, `StudentTest` is a bit of a disaster though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix a few things according to your logic. Start with `main`:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    // create array of size specified by user
    Student[] students = createArray();

    // populate this array with data from user
    populateArray(students);

    // finally, display array contents
    displayArray(students);

}//end main method
```

In `createArray` create and return array of correct size:

```
// read user input as arraySize
return new Student[arraySize];
```

In `populateArray` make sure you modify passed array with data from user, i.e. :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Student student = new Student(); // new student

    //set name
    System.out.println("Enter Student Name: ");
    student.setName(scanner.nextLine());

    //set ID number
    System.out.println("Enter Student ID Number: ");
    student.setIdNumber(scanner.nextLong());

    inputArray[i] = student; // put new student into array passed to the method

}//end for loop
```

And finally, in `displayArray` just iterate over items and print them in format you like:

```
public static void displayArray(Student[] students){

    for (Student s : students) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Name = %s, id = %d", s.getName(), s.getIdNumber());
    }
}//end method
```

And, of course, you don't really need to have 3 different methods to implement this trivial functionality, but it should work.